# Android Studio Fullscreen Background Image with android:background

Tags: android

I have been trying to make an Android app with a full screen background image, but just can't get the picture to fill the whole screen.

Here's what I have so far:

activity_main_screen.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainScreen"
android:background="@mipmap/background">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: i would put a imageview over your layout and set ScaleType to centerCrop.

Comment: what is the @mipmap?

Comment: it is used for icons and not for background images!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any images other than icons should **not** be placed in the `mipmap` folder.

According to the official Android blog:

> It’s best practice to place your app icons in mipmap- folders (not the
>   drawable- folders) because they are used at resolutions different from
>   the device’s current density. - [(source)](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html)

You will need to move `background.png` to the relevant `drawable` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try like the following:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainScreen"
android:background="@mipmap/background"

>
```

Comment: Thanks, but made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Move background.png to the drawable folder. Then change your code to

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainScreen"
android:background="@drawable/background"

>
```